# How to fetch the value of Lightning input having specific name

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

I wanted to fetch the value of the Input element by specifying name of the element.
i do have 2 input element but i need to fetch the value of input with name='press'

How can i modify my below code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are not  you using the `onchange` handler?

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Yes..that is possible,
Is there a way of queryselector syntex to capture the specific input value.
That way the code can be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the field value on button click using querySelector, but you cannot use name attribute to identify a particular lightning input field inside querySelector. You can make use of dataset attribute to do so.

Instead of name, change it to data-name in input markup definition.

```
    <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-input type="number" data-name="temp"  label="Enter a Temperature" ></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col btnMargin">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Check" title="Check" onclick={handleLusmSearch} class=""></lightning-button>
    </div>
```

In JS side, You can access it like:-

```
handleLusmSearch(event){
    const temp = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input[data-name="temp"]').value;
    console.log(temp);
}
```

If you want to get the field value on change of field value, you can make use of onchange handler. The sample code would be:-

### HTML

```
<lightning-input name="numberField" type="number" onchange={handleChange} label="Enter a number"></lightning-input>
<lightning-input name="checkboxField" type="checkbox" onchange={handleChange} label="Basic option"></lightning-input>
```

### JS

```
 numberFieldValue;  
 checkBoxFieldValue; 
 handleChange(event){
        var value;
        if(event.target.type === 'checkbox' || event.target.type === 'checkbox-button' || event.target.type === 'toggle'){
            value = event.target.checked;
        }else{
            value = event.target.value;
        }
        if(event.target.name === 'numberField'){
            this.numberFieldValue = value;
        }else if(event.target.name === 'checkboxField'){
            this.checkBoxFieldValue = value;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.